# What is Sql Server Clustered Index in Oracle terminology

Tags: sql-server, oracle, index, terminology

A clustered index in sql server like a dictionary or telephone directory. A,B,C,D it goes on.
If you look up with a name Ozgur you start O then z etc.

I would like a **simple** explaination for this concept for oracle savy users.

More information about Clustered Indexes in Sql Server.
[What is a Clustered Index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/866/what-is-a-clustered-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Oracle terminology, it is an [Index Organized Table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm), commonly referred to as an IOT.

> An index-organized table has a storage organization that is a variant of a primary B-tree. Unlike an ordinary (heap-organized) table whose data is stored as an unordered collection (heap), data for an index-organized table is stored in a B-tree index structure in a primary key sorted manner. Each leaf block in the index structure stores both the key and nonkey columns.

Comment: It is probably the closest thing to a clustered index, but it sure isn't the same thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How do they differ?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith: an IOT is only one single *thing* it's the index **and** the table at the same time. In SQL Server (if I'm not mistaken) the clustered index exists in addition to the table. The IOT is also always "clustered" by the PK of the table (because the IOT **is** the PK in some way). IIRC in SQL Server you can define a clustered index on a non-PK column.

Comment: Hi horse! IN SQL Server the clustered index also is physically the table - the table data is physically stored in the index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, so an IOT is more similar to a full-covering non-clustered index?

Comment: @NiallLitchfield: but the table data still exists, right?

Comment: @Gonsalu: probably. I guess actually a full-covering, clustered index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, after reading on IOTs, it's exactly the same thing as clustered indexes in SQL Server: a B-Tree with the index keys, and sorted leaves by the index keys. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10713/indexiot.htm#CHDJGJHG

Comment: @Gonsalu: OK, thanks. Then my understanding of a clustered index is probably wrong ;).

Comment: @Gonsalu: but one of the differences is still that SQL Server can create a clustered index on non-unique (i.e PK) columns. Btw: I found this page quite interesting: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name even when SQL allows a clustered index on a non unique column, it adds a 4 byte "uniqueifier" to the key, thus making it unique. The suggestions and best practices call for unique clustered indexes but they are allowed because sometimes you want a non unique value as a clustered key for the benefits you get from the clustered index (best example I can think of is a Date_Key that is a natural key in a date dimension and key in a fact table in yyyymmdd format. Great for range scans, inserted sequentially to avoid page splits, etc, often a filtering predicate, etc.)

Comment: @NiallLitchfield I asked one of our resident SS experts [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2458915#2458915) and you are right - even to the extent of [how secondary indexes work differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx) depending on whether the table is an IOT (or 'clustered') or a heap